# SIMILE Timeline - hosting on your own server

Tags: timeline, simile

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with hosting MIT's SIMILE Timeline on their own server. I have been trying to do so for a few days now, following the instructions provided via *http://api.simile-widgets.org/timeline/2.3.1/timeline-api.js?bundle=true*, but have not had any luck. I have downloaded the zip file which contains the files the instructions tell you to reference. I have searched google to the ends but have not found anything that is helpful.

If anyone has any knowledge of working with the SIMILE Timeline, I would greatly appreciate some advice/direction. Everything I have found seems to be pretty dated.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to ask SIMILE-Widgets questions is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/simile-widgets

This documentation worked for me: 
http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline#How-Tos

There are plenty of experienced and helpful users in that group. You will need to be clearer about what you're actually having trouble with. For example, are you getting a blank screen, an error message, etc. Are you able to provide a link to your attempt?